# How to group generalization in UML?

Tags: uml

I have model that looks like that:

[image: Generalization]

**Question:** how to correctly group a lot of generalization arrows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The UML metamodel includes the concept of generalization set which allows you group a set of generalizations (and add global constraints to them like disjoint).

Some tools support this concept but some don't. Try to overlap the lines in your schema and see if the tool understands this action as a "merge" action and groups them